# How Can I Hide Images From Gallery Which I am Taking Using FilePcker.Builder 's Camera Option?

Tags: android, gallery

I am getting Images of Customer using FilePicker.Builder's Camera Option .

This is How it Opens When i Click on TakePhote Button .

[image]

After taking images using this camera option , images are visible in Gallery **But i do not want to show images in gallery** .

Can anybody help me with this .

This is code inside TakePhoto button .

```
FilePickerBuilder.getInstance().setMaxCount(10)
                .setActivityTheme(R.style.AppTheme3)
                .pickPhoto(getActivity());
```

This OnActivityResult() method .

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case FilePickerConst.REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO:

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: ");
                for (String path : data.getStringArrayListExtra(FilePickerConst.KEY_SELECTED_PHOTOS)) {
                    String fileName = CommonMethod.getFileNameFromPath(path);

                    Log.e("DocPath : ", path);

                    if (!documentNameList.contains(fileName) && !selectPhotosPath.contains(path) && selectPhotosPath.size() < 10) {
                        selectPhotosPath.add(path);
                        File file = new File(path);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image Name: " + fileName);
                        documentNameList.add(fileName);
                        documentIdList.add(0);
                        selectPhotosBitmap.add(CommonMethod.compressImage(file, getContext()));
                    }
                }

                adapter.addItems(selectPhotosBitmap);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e(TAG, "Number Of Files: " + selectPhotosPath.size());
            }

    }
}
```

This is where documents are being stored .

E/DocPath :: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_1551349334314.jpg

Comment: You can Do this by Giving Images in `.folder extention..` Like Whatsapp Save its Status in `.Status` so you cant view the images in gallery

Comment: @WhatsGoingOn Thank you , but how can i create a folder ? by default images are storing inside Pictures folder in internal storage , Please share some code ,

Comment: @Fantomas Can you help me with this?